# Get data based on changes between datetime SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `price_history`; this table stored a price change between date.

```
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| update_timestamp        | item_code | old_price | new_price |
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2019-11-04 19:50:33.857 | XA00001   | 194357.47 | 193891.77 |
| 2019-11-03 21:53:01.910 | XA00001   | 193892.19 | 194357.47 |
| 2019-11-02 21:09:22.687 | XA00001   | 194357.47 | 193892.19 |
| 2019-11-02 05:33:39.563 | XA00001   | 194357.47 | 194357.47 |
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

and I also have table called `item_transaction`.

```
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| sell_timestamp          | item_code | qty       |
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2019-11-04 19:56:34.000 | XA00001   | 1         |
| 2019-11-03 21:54:29.000 | XA00001   | 2         | 
| 2019-11-02 21:11:36.000 | XA00001   | 2         |
| 2019-11-02 12:22:43.000 | XA00001   | 1         |
| 2019-11-02 12:22:42.000 | XA00001   | 1         |
| 2019-11-02 12:21:44.000 | XA00001   | 1         |
| 2019-11-02 05:34:43.000 | XA00001   | 1         |
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm looking for a query to get a price from `price_history` based on `sell_timestamp` from `item_transaction`.

This is the result I want:

```
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| sell_timestamp          | item_code | qty       | price     |
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2019-11-04 19:56:34.000 | XA00001   | 1         | 193891.77 |
| 2019-11-03 21:54:29.000 | XA00001   | 2         | 194357.47 |
| 2019-11-02 21:11:36.000 | XA00001   | 2         | 193892.19 |
| 2019-11-02 12:22:43.000 | XA00001   | 1         | 194357.47 |
| 2019-11-02 12:22:42.000 | XA00001   | 1         | 194357.47 |
| 2019-11-02 12:21:44.000 | XA00001   | 1         | 194357.47 |
| 2019-11-02 05:34:43.000 | XA00001   | 1         | 194357.47 |
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm only able to create a query to get a price on the same date as price changed date.

```
SELECT 
    a.sell_timestamp, a.item_code, a.qty, b.new_price AS price
FROM 
    item_transaction a
LEFT JOIN 
    price_history b ON a.item_code = b.item_code 
                    AND CAST(a.sell_timestamp AS DATE) = CAST(b.update_timestamp AS DATE)
WHERE 
    CAST(a.sell_timestamp, AS DATE) BETWEEN '2019-11-02' AND '2019-11-04'
```

Comment: Thoughts on table design here (unrelated to the question): You should only need to store the "new" price - the table essentially becomes "the price was this much starting at this point in time".  Also, you should almost certainly be storing what the item was actually sold at, not deriving it after the fact (especially if there's anything that adjust the price) - this is technically a normal form violation, but it's less of an issue for a read-only, write-forward database (which is what a receipt log is).  Perhaps that is what this query is for, though.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things easier, I would suggest you table `price_history` should store `DateFrom` and `DateTo` to keep track on the effective date time range.
Now, what I have tired is build a temp view by using `WITH` clause, to make the `price_history` to show in `DateFrom` and `DateTo`, and then join to table `item_transaction` and should be able to get your expected result.
Here is my query, please have a try.

```
;WITH price_history_data AS
(
    SELECT Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY item_code ORDER BY update_timestamp) row_num,
            item_code, update_timestamp, new_price
    FROM price_history 
),
price_history_from_to AS
(
    SELECT phd.update_timestamp AS DateFrom,
            COALESCE(phd2.update_timestamp, GETDATE()) DateTo,
            phd.new_price,
            phd.item_code
    FROM price_history_data phd
    LEFT JOIN price_history_data phd2 ON (phd.row_num = phd2.row_num-1 AND phd.item_code = phd2.item_code)
)
SELECT it.sell_timestamp, it.item_code, it.qty, phft.new_price AS price, phft.DateFrom
FROM item_transaction it
LEFT JOIN price_history_from_to phft
ON (it.item_code = phft.item_code AND it.sell_timestamp >= phft.DateFrom AND it.sell_timestamp < phft.DateTo)
ORDER BY it.sell_timestamp DESC
```

Comment: You probably want `LEAD()` to find the "next" row - also, what is the price going to be if the price hasn't been changed yet (only one row)?  Note that I would recommend that `DateFrom` be part of a calculated column or a persisted view - you don't want rows going out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Get all the previous price time intervals:

   ```sql
   SELECT a.*, b.new_price as price, DATEDIFF(ms,b.update_timestamp,a.sell_timestamp) AS interval 
   FROM item_transaction a 
   INNER JOIN price_history b ON a.sell_timestamp>b.update_timestamp
   ```
2. Order all result in step 1 with row number partition by sell_timestamp(**better by item_transaction's primary key if you have**) and order by interval:

   ```sql
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by sell_timestamp order by interval) as rn 
   FROM (
       SELECT a.*, b.new_price as price, DATEDIFF(ms,b.update_timestamp,a.sell_timestamp) AS interval 
       FROM item_transaction a 
       INNER JOIN price_history b ON a.sell_timestamp>b.update_timestamp
   ) temp
   ```
3. Filter result of step 2 with condition row number equals 1:

   ```sql
   SELECT sell_timestamp, item_code, qty, price 
   FROM(
       SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by sell_timestamp order by interval) as rn 
       FROM (
           SELECT a.*, b.new_price as price, DATEDIFF(ms,b.update_timestamp,a.sell_timestamp) AS interval 
           FROM item_transaction a 
           INNER JOIN price_history b ON a.sell_timestamp>b.update_timestamp
       ) temp
   ) temp2 where rn=1
   ```

The final query is:

```sql
SELECT sell_timestamp, item_code, qty, price 
FROM(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by sell_timestamp order by interval) as rn 
    FROM (
        SELECT a.*, b.new_price as price, DATEDIFF(ms,b.update_timestamp,a.sell_timestamp) AS interval 
        FROM item_transaction a 
        INNER JOIN price_history b ON a.sell_timestamp>b.update_timestamp
    ) temp
) temp2 where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Lead" function for getting the timestamp range the price was valid and then look for records in the time range

```
select sell_timestamp, item_code, qty,
        (
            select new_price 
               from(select update_timestamp,
                           isnull(lead(update_timestamp) over(order by update_timestamp),getdate()) until,
                           new_price
                    from price_history) a
                   where it.sell_timestamp between a.update_timestamp and a.until
        ) price
  from item_transaction it
```